# Security for local LoRA signal?

Tags: security

I want to implement two `esp32` to send -> receive sensor data over LoRa. I would like to ask if there is a way to `secure` this transmission?
Should I implement some kind of home-made data-transformation algorithm or is there a better way, like some kind of `SSL keygen`, `certificate` or something of that kind?

Comment: This question is off topic here. Sister sites that are more suitable: [security.se], [electronics.se].

Comment: @GeraldSchneider or even Stack Overflow, as it's development related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [encrypt your messages](https://rweather.github.io/arduinolibs/crypto.html) and then transmit it through the air. The endpoint can decrypt it.